# Why I need to specify working directories and path?

Tags: python

Whenever I do a project for computer science, I have to make sure all of my files are located in the same folder, or I'll have errors. If I want to use a file from somewhere else, I have to insert it into the path. I do these things but don't fully understand what is happening or why. Why is the path changed in the runtime environment?

Answer (score 1):

When you run a python script you are executing it in the current working directory `/home/user/python.py` for example. That means this script since it lives in `/home/user` has access to everything in that path. However you should be able to access any other directory from here as long as the permissions are setup right. You would do that by using *relative paths*. so for example `/home/user/python.py` could access a file that is `/home/example/file.txt` by giving it the path `../example/file.txt` from the python project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the path using sys.path.append? If you don't want to do that every time then you can set (Windows) %PYTHONPATH% to include your custom path. That's what I do for my include folder.